# If L:K is a finite extension such that $|\Gamma(L:K)| = [L:K]$, is L:K necessarily normal?

Tags: galois-theory

I've been thinking about this question and I know that if $L:K$ is normal and finite where L, K are subfields of $\mathbb{C}$, then $|\Gamma(L:K)| = [L:K]$. I was wondering if, assuming that L:K is a finite extension such that $|\Gamma(L:K)| = [L:K]$, can you conclude  L:K necessarily normal?

I don't know how I would even start this / if there is an easy counterexample if it is false so any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: What does the notation $\Gamma(L:K)$ indicate? The group of field automorphisms of $L$ fixing $K$?

Comment: @AlexWertheim yes! sorry about not specifying that.

Comment: No problem! The answer to your question is yes. In fact, you can even say more: if $|Aut(L/K)| = [L:K]$, then $L$ is the splitting field of a separable polynomial over $K$. See Theorem 3.13 of these wonderful notes by Keith Conrad for proof: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/galoiscorr.pdf

Comment: By the way, your first claim is false: it is not sufficient that $L/K$ be normal and finite for $|Aut(L/K)| = [L:K]$ to hold. You also need that $L/K$ is a separable extension. For a counterexample, let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p$, and consider the extension $F(X)/F(X^{p})$. You can check that this is a normal extension of degree $p$, but $Aut(F(X)/F(X^{p}))$ is trivial! See also Theorem 4.1 of the notes linked above.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Oh you're right! That was my bad, my book always assumes we are working in $\mathbb{C}$ so I forgot to specify that

Comment: @klamont15 Do you really mean $\Gamma(L/K) = \operatorname{Aut}(L/K)$ the group of $K$-automorphisms of $L$? Things I've read usually  use $\Gamma(L/K)$ to denote the "Galois set" of $K$-embeddings $L \to \bar K$ of $L$ into an algebraic closure.